# How to group by the first element of an array?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I work with documents such as:

```
{
    "foo" : { "objectid" : "39", "stuff" : "65" },
    "yearpublished" : ["1979"],
    "bar" : "1263"
}
```

`yearpublished` is an array and I would like to group my collection by the first value in this array and then count the amount of documents related.

I have written this query:

```
db.foobar.aggregate([
    { $group : {
        _id : '$yearpublished',
        count: { $sum: 1 }
    }}
])
```

and get:

```
{
    "result" : [ 
        { "_id" : ["1923"], "count" : 1.0000000000000000 }, 
        { "_id" : ["1864"], "count" : 1.0000000000000000 }
    ]
}
```

But I'm looking for this kind of result (i. e. first element only):

```
{
    "result" : [ 
        { "_id" : "1923", "count" : 1.0000000000000000 }, 
        { "_id" : "1864", "count" : 1.0000000000000000 }
    ]
}
```

I've also tried  `_id : { $first: '$yearpublished.0' },` or  `_id : { $first: '$yearpublished[0]' },` without success.

How can I group by the first element of the array **yearpublished** ?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Unfortunately right now the only way to do this is to extract the [`$first`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/first/) element from the array after processing [`$unwind`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/). Then of course you would have to [`$group`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/) again:

```js
db.foobar.aggregate([
    { "$unwind": "$yearpublished" },
    { "$group": {
        "_id": "$_id",
        "yearpublished": { "$first": "$yearpublished" }
    }},
    { "$group": {
        "_id": "$yearpublished",
        "count": { "$sum": 1 }
    }}
])
```

Thats the only current way to get the "first" element from an array, by deconstructing it and using the operator to get the entry.

Future releases will have `$arrayElemAt` which can do this by index within a single stage:

```js
db.foobar.aggregate([
    { "$group": {
        "_id": { "$arrayElemAt": [ "$yearpublished", 0 ] },
        "count": { "$sum": 1 }
    }}
])
```

But presently the aggregation framework does not deal with "dot notation" index usage such as standard "projection" with `.find()` does, and will not, hence the new operations.

Answer (score 1):

Starting `Mongo 4.4`, the aggregation operator [`$first`](https://docs.mongodb.com/master/reference/operator/aggregation/first-array-element/) can be used to access the first element of an array.

Which gives in our case, within a group stage:

```
// { "yearpublished": ["1979", "2003"] }
// { "yearpublished": ["1954", "1979"] }
// { "yearpublished": ["1954"] }
db.collection.aggregate([
  { $group: {
    "_id": { $first: "$yearpublished" },
    "count": { $sum: 1 }
  }}
])
// { "_id" : "1954", "count" : 2 }
// { "_id" : "1979", "count" : 1 }
```